# Application crashes while running in Device/Emulator

Tags: java, android, soap, android-ksoap2

My application is getting crashed while running. But if I create a `Java` class and execute the same code (removing `Toast`), it is working properly.

Any thoughts?

I've added `ksoap2-android-full-2.1.2` in my `Android` and `Java` project's class path.

**Code**:

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;


SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);    
request.addProperty("UserID", "admin");
request.addProperty("Password", "admin");

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject) (envelope.bodyIn);

    if (Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty("UserValidationResponse").toString()) == 0) {
        userAuthenticated = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Authenticated...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Not Authenticated...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
12-27 18:54:25.003: E/dalvikvm(690): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.micros.retail.LoginActivity.doLogin
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  ... 11 more
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at com.micros.retail.LoginActivity.doLogin(LoginActivity.java:56)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  at com.micros.retail.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:48)
12-27 18:54:41.203: E/AndroidRuntime(690):  ... 14 more
```

Comment: have you added ksoap2-android-full-2.1.2 into libs folder of your android project?

Comment: Awesome dude... Thanks... Add it as answer, I'll accept... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ksoap2-android-full-2.1.2` jar under libs folder of your android project.